# How to get Buttons content as property in a called flyout in an UWP app?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

**Usecase**

I've a bunch (8) of buttons which opens an Flyover via the set style property.

The flyover contains an "Apply" button. The button will trigger an Command which does something in the view model related to the source's buttons content (which is 1 to 8).

**Problem**

How get I the content value of my button that triggers the Flyover to my command?

I thought that `CommandParameter={Text ElementName=Source}` should do what I want, but no it did not.

**Resources**

```
<Style x:Key="PixelButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Flyout" Value="{StaticResource PixelColorPickerFlyOut}" />
</Style>

<Flyout x:Key="PixelColorPickerFlyOut">
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Picker -->
                <ColorPicker x:Name="PixelColorPicker"
                             IsAlphaEnabled="False"
                             IsColorChannelTextInputVisible="False"
                             IsAlphaSliderVisible="False"
                             IsAlphaTextInputVisible="False"
                             IsHexInputVisible="False"
                             IsColorSliderVisible="False"
                             Width="300"/>

                <!-- Button row -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            Margin="0 20 0 0">
                    <Button Content="Apply"
                            Width="100"
                            Margin="0 0 10 0"
                            Command="{Binding ApplyColorCommand}"/>

                    <Button Content="Cancel"
                            Width="100"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Source}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
```

**Usage**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PixelButtonStyle}" Content="" />
```

**Update 1**

I also tried to use as flyout button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=DataContext.ApplyColorPickerCommand}" 
        Content="Apply" />
```

and as button that triggeres the flyout:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PixelButtonStyle}" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" 
        Content="1" 
        Background="Green"/>
```

but it had no positive effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure if I understand your request properly. Do you actually mean this, you have 8 buttons and each of them can raise the flyout. So you want to know which button actually raised the flyout? If this is what you want, maybe you can give the following code a try:

First, each FramewrokElement has a property called tag. So here is a demo XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Tag="button no.1" Command="{Binding MyBtnClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Tag}" Content="set empty content"/>
</Grid>
```

Then if you are using RelayCommand, we can get the tag value from this class:

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when RaiseCanExecuteChanged is called.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this RelayCommand can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
    /// this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the RelayCommand on the current command target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
    /// this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    /// 
    **private string btntag;
    public string BtnTag
    {
        get { return btntag; }
        set { btntag= value; }
    }**


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
         **btntag= parameter as string;**
        _execute();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to raise the CanExecuteChanged event
    /// to indicate that the return value of the CanExecute
    /// method has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, you can get it in your command:

```
private RelayCommand btnclickcommmand;

    public RelayCommand MyBtnClickCommand
    {
        get { return btnclickcommmand; }
        set { btnclickcommmand = value; }
    }

 btnclickcommmand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            //TODO            
            mytag = btnclickcommmand.BtnTag;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mytag+"Button create the flyout");
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. My goal was to find a only-XAML solution but I think, this is not possible. Thanks!